# Chef 12.5-style custom resource: install a gem required by the load_current_value block?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a Chef 12.5-style custom resource that requires a gem to be installed before I "require" it in the load_current_value block.  I tried to use a `chef_gem` resource, but I get a NoMethodError on chef_gem when I use it there.  This works:

```
load_current_value do
  Chef::Resource::ChefGem.new 'inifile' do
    compile_time true
  end
  require 'inifile'
  # ... load_current_value code
end
```

... but explicitly calling `Chef::Resource::ChefGem.new` seems wrong, or at least "inelegant."

This makes the gem available to the actions, and that's convenient.  But I'm wondering if there a more appropriate way to install a chef_gem in (or ahead of) the load_current_value block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly from chef 12.8 it's possible to [specify gems in metadata.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html#settings) (look for gem keyword):

```
Specifies a gem dependency to be installed via the chef_gem resource after
all cookbooks are synchronized, but before any other cookbook loading is
done. Use this attribute once per gem dependency.
```

I think this is the 'thing' you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That is the correct answer.  This works in the general case and solves my ``load_current_value`` issue.

I was put off the track because using ``gem 'mysql2'`` in this way crashes, (hopefully a temporary problem, due to a missing package dependency) so I had abandoned -and forgotten about- using the metadata solution.

Comment: The problem is that it installs the gem when chef starts up, which is before a compiler or the mysql libraries are available (assuming you install those via recipes). This can lead to difficulty with ordering.

Comment: .. and it requires your cheffed hosts can all hit rubygems.org or a proxy for ad-hoc gem downloading.  

The security concerns are interesting.